# Best Scheme implementation for Emacs and The Little Schemer?

Tags: emacs, scheme, emacs24, the-little-schemer, geiser

I've tried Geiser and I keep getting this error message:

```
Unable to start REPL:
Searching for program: permission denied, guile.exe
```

I'm on Windows 7 by the way. Also, here's my Geiser path in my .emacs:

```
(load-file "~/.emacs.d/elpa/geiser-20140326.951/geiser.el")
```

I'm not sure how to fix this since Google isn't returning anything useful and I'm not overly familiar with Emacs or Geiser. I'd really appreciate some help with this or a better/easier Scheme implementation so I can finally start TLS.

Comment: Try cygwin or ubuntu. The setup is straightforward there.

Comment: I can't help you with Emacs, but I would have used [DrRacket](http://racket-lang.org/) and used one of the teaching languages or R5RS. Then you can step by expanding the code, debug step by step as in any other language and you have all the features expected of an IDE for LISPs.

Comment: It sounds like geiser.el uses guile as its default scheme. Try `M-x customize-group RET geiser RET` or failing that `C-u M-x apropos-variable RET geiser- RET`, and then `C-s` for `guile` in the results. Hopefully that'll show you which variable to set.

Comment: Could the problem be caused by me not having the Guile REPL installed? I thought it was included with the Geiser install. How do I install Guile alongside Geiser? This is probably a dumb question, but I really don't know how this all works (at least not very well).

Comment: If it's looking for guile by default, then certainly installing it might make things "just work". I'm assuming that you can configure geiser to work with a different scheme (as I had also been assuming you had a scheme installed already). Rptx's answer sounds good.

Answer (score 3):

Geiser does not provide Scheme. You need to install them for it to use. It requires Racket 5.3.4 or better, or guille 2.0.9 or better, as seen on this page:

http://www.nongnu.org/geiser/geiser_2.html#Installation

This is a link for Racket:

http://racket-lang.org/download/

Sorry can't help you any more, but I don't have windows. I use geiser with guile under linux.